# Overflow and non-responsive page

Tags: html, css, overflow, bootstrap-5

For the past couple of hours I've been trying to make my website less responsive to no luck. I want to keep my webpage and its elements exactly the same even when the screen size gets too small for the content on the page. When the screen size gets too small I want horizontal scrolling to be enabled instead of the layout moving around(Here's an example of a website that has this feature: [Example website](https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=CJ2PNq0Z1Zfb-EYDCtOUPiPaI-Arqz9_iccub2tPVEam9zgUIABACILlUKAJgyb7JhsSjyBegAZHrg8sDyAEBqQKOUXS34PJuPsgD2CCqBFtP0P15oI5Vd9vcOn-3BJFU7BTks132dRd1aP6CGssih9hGEjD8hKyL-8PyKrQH-QBI6LAU1rB2dBWA1I29P0zVI6lF1CCSlpzw7vSpMw-Tc1sm8oRLrYzmLKxrwASIqfKs3AOABZBOiAWPnbTtNqAGZoAHxayNOIgHAZAHAagH67ixAqgHpr4bqAe5mrECqAfz0RuoB-7SG6gH_5yxAqgHytwbqAeSr7ECqAe7pLECqAeSprECqAfYprECqAfetbECqAfbqrECqAfQqrECqAfcsLECqAe_ubECqAfqsbECqAequLECqAeUuLECqAfsuLECqAe-t7ECoAj6kqcEsAgB0ggmEAIyBIPggA46CcLhgICAgASCQEIBBEjR7PMqUAlYtoDN7IuEgwOaCRBodHRwczovL3Bva2kuY29tsQlH9Bwj_wkljrkJR_QcI_8JJY74CQGYCwGqDAIIAdoMCAoDINABEgEC6AwGqg0CVVPIDQGCFAkIAxIFZ2FtZXPIFPaeiPmK-sfWVtAVAfgWAYAXAZIXCRIHCAEQAxjxAeAXAg&ae=2&gclid=CjwKCAiAvdCrBhBREiwAX6-6UighJXzc3yrjdkn60_diS4m2vDYzapnHXcpD2df2Ee6MK61-2YVavRoC8cAQAvD_BwE&ved=2ahUKEwio2sPsi4SDAxWWle4BHbGzAkEQ0Qx6BAgLEAM&nis=2&dct=1&cid=CAASFORoQEmlBnYvp2ffqrsIIkskGbw6&dblrd=1&sival=AF15MEDXbm_WjyViEt0McZKjHE7hRLiH13ciHJjzK__4xoUIMvJkTwo0aQURdsdPRzILgCZw-rs8wZT4CXdDs_NNfQPtf6ydcWbe74q7Aalns-SlcZxDjor78BhxgRJVbpeglEGqmK78mHKVhe5YkBHH8hQO_S32waAejCNHHzodsSkTWQ3t_HM&sig=AOD64_2S3h_FmFSG1I_UQbhh4ixDRF_doQ&adurl=https://poki.com%3Fcampaign%3D14724959887%26adgroup%3D127869424776%26extensionid%3D%26targetid%3Dkwd-11771561%26location%3D9030010%26matchtype%3De%26network%3Dg%26device%3Dc%26devicemodel%3D%26creative%3D669862047750%26keyword%3Dgames%26placement%3D%26target%3D)).

```css
.scrolling-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto; /* Enable horizontal scrolling */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent content from wrapping to the next line */
}

.row {
  display: flex; /* Flex display */
  flex-wrap: nowrap; /* Prevent wrapping inside the row */
}

/* Base height for small game */
.small-game .card {
  height: 100px; /* Adjust this value as needed */
}

/* Medium game height is twice that of small game */
.medium-game .card {
  height: 200px; /* 2 times the small game height */
}

/* Large game height is three times that of small game */
.large-game .card {
  height: 300px; /* 3 times the small game height */
}

/* Ensure the image fills the card */
.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Dalton's Game Portfolio</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
  
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container mt-5">
    <h1 class="text-center">Dalton's Game Portfolio</h1>
    <div class="scrolling-wrapper">
      <div class="row g-0">
          <!-- Large games -->
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="card large-game">
            <img src="path-to-large-game-image.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Large Game">
          </div>
        </div>
  
        <!-- Medium Game -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="card medium-game">
            <img src="path-to-medium-game-image.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Medium Game">
          </div>
        </div>
  
        <!-- Small Game -->
        <div class="col-lg-2">
          <div class="card small-game">
            <img src="path-to-small-game-image.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Small Game">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- Bootstrap JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure whether it's because of the bootstraps grid system or what but parts of my grid keep moving below other elements as the screen size gets too small. If anyone could please help me that'd be great, I also understand that a lot of you guys wont be happy with using pxs for my height but I'm just trying to fix one thing at a time :)! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your three columns (Large, Medium, and Small Game) will line up vertically because you've defined them to be columns for anything under lg. If you want your entire website to stop shrinking below a set size, you can apply a `min-width` to your `body` tag.

Comment: @RichDeBourke I set a min-width to the body element in CSS and it did in fact make it so the Large, Medium, and Small game images stayed on the same line but the medium and small game images were inlarged to the same size as the large image. Any way to keep the images from changing sizes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with images as you didn't include any images in your code snippet, nor is your CSS integrated into the snippet. Can you update your snippet to include placeholder images that are the correct size? You can use a service like [placehold.co](https://placehold.co/).